# Transpose multiple columns into rows, but convert the transposed columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

With this dataframe:

```
+--------+---------+------+----------+
| metric | control | test | duration |
+--------+---------+------+----------+
| logins | 4       | 2    | short    |
+--------+---------+------+----------+
```

I want to transpose the `control` and `test` column values into multiple rows under their own column called `value`, but I also want to consolidate the `control` and `test` columns into one column called `cohort`. The result would then be:

```
+--------+---------+-------+----------+
| metric | cohort  | value | duration |
+--------+---------+-------+----------+
| logins | control | 4     | short    |
+--------+---------+-------+----------+
| logins | test    | 2     | short    |
+--------+---------+-------+----------+
```

I know this involves a melt or pivot function, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You are likely looking for [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) : ``df.melt(['metric', 'duration'], var_name='cohort')``